# How do I specify a "JSON Raw Message" in API object using Swagger 2.0 or OpenApi 3.x?

Tags: json, go, swagger-2.0, openapi

I am documenting a REST API (developed in Go) using Swagger 2.0 and one of the structures used by an API Response includes several fields that are declared to be of type "Json.RawMessage" in Go. I can't find any appropriate "data type" in the Swagger specification that would cover this. The closest that I could imagine would be a string in "byte" format. But that isn't even close. Any ideas would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

[`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) is just way of parsing of json message. It allows to delay parsing of some fields or all the message.

It doesn't affect structure or format of response so you don't need to specify it in openapi spec by any way.

The only thing I can guess, that some of the fields could have different schemas from one response to another. So you can't document all of them in the same time (as far as I know openapi features), and all you can do is to describe it as just general `"object"`. And describe possible schemas somewhere in documentation.

Comment: The API that I am documented submits a request to the system database and returns the JSON response  from the database as "glob" (i.e. json.rawMessage) and allows the original requester to decipher. Therefore, one of the fields of the response object contains this "glob" . Want to know if there is a way to describe this in swagger/openapi.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant.
I've never needed such feature, but may be what you are looking for is this: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#schema-vs-content